# how to interprate this xml fields (converting to SQL via msxml)

Tags: sql, xml, msxml

I would like to create sql query, exactly same, as msxml would create. 
For example I've got this xml:

```
 <COLUMN name="NAME" type="INTEGER" not_null="true" sub_key="2" fk_table="T_SOME_TABLE"
 fk_column="FK_VALUE" fk_cardinality="1..n" fk_aggregate="false" dict_id="30" advanced="false"
 uiname="Input type" project="SOME_PROJECT">
 <INFO>
  SOME INFO
 </INFO>
</COLUMN>
```

and I do not know what query would it create, because I do not know what is the result of fk_cardinality fk_aggregate in SQL query.

Could you tell me how will look that query?

Comment: have you checked my answer? Please vote up and/or mark as accepted if helpful, thx

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
declare @x XML='<COLUMN name="NAME" type="INTEGER" not_null="true" sub_key="2" fk_table="T_SOME_TABLE"
 fk_column="FK_VALUE" fk_cardinality="1..n" fk_aggregate="false" dict_id="30" advanced="false"
 uiname="Input type" project="SOME_PROJECT">
 <INFO>
  SOME INFO
 </INFO>
</COLUMN>';

SELECT @x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@name','varchar(max)') AS [name]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@type','varchar(max)') AS [type]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@not_null','bit') AS [not_null]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@sub_key','int') AS [sub_key]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@fk_table','varchar(max)') AS [fk_table]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@fk_column','varchar(max)') AS [fk_column]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@fk_cardinality','varchar(max)') AS [fk_cardinality]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@fk_aggregate','bit') AS [fk_aggregate]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@dict_id','int') AS [dict_id]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@advanced','bit') AS [advanced]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@uiname','varchar(max)') AS [uiname]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/@project','varchar(max)') AS [project]
      ,@x.value('/COLUMN[1]/INFO[1]','varchar(max)') AS [INFO]
```